# Convert ArrayList to List<string[]>

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a whole bunch of functions which return the data type ArrayList. Each list item contains a string value which has multiple values all delimited by a "\t" and up until now I've been appending a text box with the data. I've done this so I can take the output and copy/paste straight into Excel as it was a simple requirement up till now..

I would like to convert the ArrayList (which contains multiple tab delimited strings) to a List of string arrays, i.e.

```
List<string[]>
```

This is so I can then attempt to fill a DataGridView control.

Anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
List<string> list = arrayList.Cast<string>()
         .SelectMany(s => s.Split('\t'))
         .ToList();
```

This casts every object in the arrayList to a string, splits each string in a set of strings, and flattens the "set of sets" into one list of strings.

Or this, if you don't want to flatten the set:

```
List<string[]> list = arrayList.Cast<string>()
     .Select(s => s.Split('\t'))
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, cast your arrayList to an enumerable of string.
Then for each string, split it into another enumerable of string, with `\t` separator, and flatten it to an array.

```
List<string[]> listOfArray = myArrayList.Cast<string>()
                                        .Select(s => s.Split('\t').ToArray())
                                        .ToList();
```